# Spark on YARN unexpected number of executors with Google Cloud Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to submit a spark application on a cluster with the following specs on GCP Dataproc:

- 3 worker nodes each with 15GB RAM and 4 cores
- 1 master node 7.5GB RAM and 2 cores

Following the guides i found on memory and executor tuning on YARN i derived the following values for the application parameters:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("test") \
    .master("yarn")\
    .config('spark.submit.deployMode','client')\
    .config("spark.executor.instances", "3")\
    .config("spark.executor.memory","10g")\
    .config("spark.executor.cores","3")\
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
```

as far as `spark.executor.memory` is concerned i should be well into the limits since i've reserved 1gb RAM for OS and Hadoop Daemons, therefore consindering memory overhead my limit should be

```
max(384MB, .07 * spark.executor.memory)---> max(384MB, .07*14GB)=max(384mb,0,98GB)= approx 1GB
```

so 15-2GB=13GB  and i specified 10GB just to be safe.
Available cores are 4-1=3 since as i just said 1 core is reserved.

I would expect to see in the application UI 3 executors but i only get 2, i also tried by specifing `spark.executor.cores=2` instead of 2 witho no avail.

Am i missing something?

thanks

Comment: Can you try adding `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false`? Also note that YARN NodeManager doesn't get all the 15GB of the worker memory.

Comment: thank you very much, by adding that property it works as intended. I was wondering if there's a reason why clusters with autoscaling policy can't be stopped. Not very practical if i want to manage it by a planned schedule

Comment: I added an answer, could you accept? For autoscaling and stop, please ask in a separate question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataproc enables Spark dynamic allocation by default, so you need to set `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false` to use static allocation.

Also note that YARN NodeManager doesn't get all of the worker node memory, a portion (~20%) of it is reserved for services including NodeManager itself. Check the YARN UI or config for the actual memory.